# Read Token Contract Information

Tags: polkadot, polkadot-js, frontier, moonbeam

I would like to read contract information(especially name, symbol, decimal, owner) from token contracts like shown here: https://moonbeam.moonscan.io/token/0x818ec0a7fe18ff94269904fced6ae3dae6d6dc0b#readContract

How do I read that from on-chain? Also, how do I figure out if a contract is a token contract?

context: this is for an indexer project.

Comment: I think once you've decoded the scale, then you have to decode it on the eth side. I'm guessing that https://github.com/rust-ethereum/ethabi should be able to do it though have not tried this out yet.